# Regular expression to include numeric only or character only or ignore first two conditions if alpha numeric

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I wrote Regular expression for the below cases :

- only numbers(length:4)
- only alphabets(should contain vowel)

```
([0-9]{1,4})|((?=[a-z]*[aeiou])[a-z]*)
```

eg: 9987, tyde

How to add the below condition?

- Ignore the first two cases if the string contains alphanumeric
  characters.
  eg: 9ty87

Comment: Please add some examples. A string that "contains alphanumeric characters" should match both.

Comment: `only characters(should contain vowel)` is in fact 2 conditions.

Comment: The first two are then contained in the last condition, so in that case it doesn't make much sense to specify these anyway.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I don't think it is so simple. I think that the last condition means "only letters and digit but a least one letter and one digit" (~alphanumeric) and the first condition: "only digits, but less than 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I decypher well your question, I think your are looking for that:

- a string with only digits and between one and four characters
- a string with only letters with at least a vowel
- a string with only letters and digits with at least one letter and one digit.

pattern:

```
/^(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][a-z]*|[a-z]+[0-9][a-z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-z][a-z0-9]*)$/i
```

or more factorized

```
/^(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:[0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*)?|[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]*(?:[aeiou][a-z]*|[a-z]+[0-9][a-z0-9]*))$/i
```

It is a simple alternation (I don't think you need something more complicated). So only one of the branches will succeed.

Note that anchors `^` and `$` are essential for this kind of task to ensure that whole string is taken in account.

Comment: But that will be rather useless since the first two cases are contained in the last one. In other words, one can drop the first two...

Comment: and another problem I think is that it can be the case that the numeric character is placed before the alpha-character. Is this case covered by this regex?

Comment: @CommuSoft: of course. (last alternative in the first pattern, first alternative in the last pattern)